# How to load different drawable resource for different layouts in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application,I have tow alternative layout files and two alternative drawable resource images. My res directory structure is as follows:

```
res/drawable-hdpi/image.png  
res/drawable-mdpi/image.png

res/layout-large/main.xml
res/layout/main.xml
```

in manifest file

```
<supports-screens 
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="false"/>
```

My app loads both the layout files `res/layout-large/main.xml`  and `res/layout/main.xml` but, both the layouts load image from `res/drawable-mdpi/image.png` and does not load `res/drawable-hdpi/image.png`. Please help me in this respect I would be very thankful to you for this act of kindness. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `-large` qualifier is a totally different thing than the `-hdpi` qualifier. If your app loads from `-mdpi` then that's because you run it on mdpi devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is to use [configuration qualifiers.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

It seems you are really misunderstanding what these folders do.
Your android will select folder based on it's **screen size** or **pixel-density** of device on which u run it

If Your device has a medium Pixel density and a large screen. So it selects its resources from the res folders with those given qualifiers.

res/layout-large/my_layout.xml

and images from

```
res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png
```

You cannot tell your device to get images from the hdpi folder because it does not have a high pixel density.

So you could either create a folder called

```
res/drawable-large-mdpi/
```

specifically for your device.

Or just make sure the right images are in the right folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can create drawable-large-mdpi folder to use the drawables for your layouts which are under layout-large folder.

Comment: Is this going to help? It seems @user1703737 has not understood the difference between dpi and size related qualifiers.